# if statement issue

Tags: php

I have a variable called root. The value for this variable is 0

```
$root = 0;

if($root == "readmore"){

            $root = 1701;
        }
```

somehow for some weird reason if $root is 0 it still enteres the if statement above? I have no idea what it could be

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322789/if0-echo-wtf-php-why-cant-you-compare-things-sanely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, with type-juggling, `0` is considered equal to `"readmore"`. You are asking PHP to compare a string to an integer, and it will interpret any string that doesn't contain digits as a `0`.

If you use `if ($root === "readmore") ...`, PHP will check the *type* as well as the value of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

basically, you are doing this comparison :

```
if (0 == 'readmore') {
  // ...
}
```

Which means 'readmore' will be converted to an integer ; and 'readmore', converted to an integer, is 0.

See [Type Juggling](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) in the manual, about that, and also [String conversion to numbers](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), which states *(quoting)* :

> If the string starts with valid
>   numeric data, this will be the value
>   used. Otherwise, the value will be 0
>   (zero).

You might want to use the === operator, which will prevent that kind of conversion :

```
if($root === "readmore") {
  // You will not enter here, if $root is 0
}
```

See [Comparison Operators](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$root = 0;

if($root === "readmore"){

        $root = 1701;
    }
```

To check the type as well.