# PHP comparion doesnt work..why?

Tags: php, comparison

i have this code:

```
    $password_introducido = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->setPassword($value['password_actual']);

    $password_almacenado = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getPassword();

    var_dump("kfjsdlkjf");
    var_dump($password_almacenado);
    var_dump($password_almacenado);

    if($password_introducido == $password_almacenado){

        die("entrosopi");


    }
```

that prints this:

> string 'kfjsdlkjf' (length=9)
>
> string
>   'c9c40d11b29ac0f5bdef3be51ce61187582c3ae1'
>   (length=40)
>
> string
>   'c9c40d11b29ac0f5bdef3be51ce61187582c3ae1'
>   (length=40)

IMHO, it should print "entrosopi", but it doesnt. Why?

If i instead write

> if(!$password_introducido ==
>   $password_almacenado)

it prints "entrosopi".

Javi

Comment: You are printing the value of `$password_almacenado` twice. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You realize you are outputting the same string right?

Try this:

```
var_dump("kfjsdlkjf");
var_dump($password_introducido);
var_dump($password_almacenado);
```

Tell us what it outputs.

They are most likely NOT equal to each other.

Comment: No it's not. The first one will convert `$password_introducido` to a boolean, `NOT` it and then compare *that* to `$password_almacenado`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the functions (most likely setPassword) is encrypting/hashing the value for security.

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` for exact, literal comparison.

For details, see this related question: [if(0 == '%') echo "WTF, Php, why can't you compare things sanely?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322789/if0-echo-wtf-php)